# Illustrator vector graphics to AS3 SWF for Flash Builder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe-illustrator

I need to convert Illustrator images to be able to use them in FLASH (AS3).

Illustrator projects contains 1 to n layers. I Would like to convers each project to single SWF to be able to do ColorTransform on selected layer in FLASH (AS3).

I've noticed that if i just simply export Illustrator to SWF then it uses AS2 and i can't change specific layer (no numChildren, type of object AVM1Movie).

**Is there an easy way to convert Illustrator multi-layer vector images to SWF (AS3) to be able to ColorTransform only one specific layer in FLASH project (loading them (SWF's), for example, with Loader.load)?**

P.S. I plan to use newest tools (from CC platform) - Illusrator, Flash Builder, Flash Professional.

Comment: Flash Pro has a not bad AI importer, just copy/paste art from AI to Flash pro new fla file

Comment: @Stefan Cebulak fsbmain's suggestion is good: setup your import options in Flash because you can actually create a MovieClip and name it from an Illustrator layer which would immediately be available  in actionscript. Another option would be the FXG format, but personally I've [successfully](http://www.hirschandmann.com/2013/siemens-crystal/) used imported AI > Flash, named/cleaned up masks, then compiled the fla a swc library I can reuse in an pure as3 project. I guess another option would be exporting SWF from Illustrator but either using AI Layers to SWF Symbols or AI Layers to SWF Files.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza this is working very nice, I just want to add that i had to Import AI to FLASH (layers to flash layers), then convert each layer to symbols to be able to name them, then export FLASH to SWF as Movie or as Image - both worked fine :]. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Cool! @fsbmain maybe you should put your suggestion down as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy of my comment to the answer, as question is solved and should be treated by SO as unanswered )

I always use Flash Pro AI importer for such types of tasks - import assets from AI to SWF. You can copy/paste graphics from AI to Fla file opened in Flash Pro or use `file->import to stage` Flash Pro option.

Answer (score 0):

As fsbmain and GeorgeProfenza said in comments above, I was able to import AI directly to stage of FLASH PRO (layers to flash layers). Then i've converted each layer elements to symbols and name them. Then i've exported whole FLASH project to SWF (Movie or Image - both worked). And i was able to get each layer from parent SWF, retrieve their names and transform them.

That would be an answer alright :]. Thanks once more.